# Amazon Timestream - can I select an array element from a measure_value

Tags: arrays, select, amazon-timestream

I have a measure_value::varchar that is say `[32603072,20213608,1314736]` and named `memory`.

How would I select the 1st element of that array only ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of string functions to convert into array, like

- replace to remove brackets
- split to parse the objects

Then you can use normal array operators. Example here

```
select my_array[1] from (
    select 
        split(replace(replace(my_string,'[',''),']',''), ',') as my_array 
    from (
        select '[32603072,20213608,1314736]' as my_string
    )
)
```

Result:

### |_col0|

| 32603072|

to make replace simpler, maybe you also can try regexp_replace() to remove the brackets first, but I am not too familiar how to write this expression

Comment: thatnks will give it a try. Seems like I might need to flatten the data structure rather.